# "hidden" with brackets doesn't work in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I add `[hidden]="true"` to an HTML element in Angular, but the element is still visible. I noticed that when I remove the `[]` from around `hidden`, the element is now hidden as desired. Why won't `[hidden]="true"` work with brackets? I see many references to it on stackoverflow and elsewhere but can't get it to work. Is this deprecated?

Comment: It's looks like work (just check in FireFox 101.0.1, Chrome 102.0.5005.115 and Edge 102.0.1245.44 for Windows in a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dz2gx9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) -Angular 14-. BTW, you can use `[style.display]="'none'"` (or using a condition `[style.display]="condition?'none':null"`

Answer (score 2):

try this. hope it will help you.

```
<div [hidden]="'true'"><div/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work like you explained. Otherwise something else is overwriting hidden. For example:

Some styles can overwrite `hidden`. Styles and classes may be inherited from somewhere?

```
<input [hidden]="true" style="display: block">
```

It would be possible to explicitly not allow that. This might be useful if you don't want to change conflicting classes rather just force this on.

```css
[hidden] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Alternative could be to use `dispaly: none`:

```html
<input [style.display]="'none'">
```

This input is hidden but still in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for your responses. I just realized this is because I'm trying to use this inside of `index.html`, which is outside of the Angular entry point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the style "visibility" inside your html file.
visibility is either "visible" or "hidden"

```
<div [style.visibility]="'visible'"></div>

<div [style.visibility]="'hidden'"></div>

<div [style.visibility]="showMyDiv ? 'visible' : 'hidden'"></div>
```

With, in your .TS file:

```
showMyDiv() {
// return true or false
}
```